# How to clear a dojox.grid.DataGrid to Update the grid

Tags: dojox.grid, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojo

I have a grid filled with ajax, the user enters new data and call back to the ajax method that fills the grid, the problem I have is that the grid are duplicate data, I have tried before upgrading the grid to fill with a empty strore but does not work,

```
var gridColeccion = dijit.byId("colectionGrid");
var dummy = {items: []};
var newEventStoreColeccion = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({clearOnClose:true,data:dummy});
newEventStoreColeccion.fetch();
gridColeccion.setStore(newEventStoreColeccion);
gridColeccion._refresh();


    folderConsult(token); // This metod fill the grid again
```

---

// This is part of code in folderConsult;

```
  var datosColeccion = {
                items:    itemsColeccion
        };

 var gridColecccion = dijit.byId("colectionGrid");  
 nuevasColecciones= new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({clearOnClose:true,data: datosColeccion});
 nuevasColecciones.fetch();
 gridColecccion.setStore(nuevasColecciones);
 gridColecccion._refresh();
```

I hope someone can help me, THX.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(grid.store._getItemsArray().length!=0)
{
   grid.store.deleteItem(grid.store._getItemsArray()[0]);
}
grid.store.save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `nuevasColecciones.close()` instead of `nuevasColecciones.fetch()` and provide a `url` param instead of the `data` param. That should refresh the data in the store, and as long as you have already posted the new data, you will get all of the objects back